# ¿Qué quiere decir "bramante"?

Tags: significado

¿Qué quiere decir *bramante* en *El último viaje del buque fantasma* de Gabriel García Márquez? Según el DLE [*bramante*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=62WR1Ij) es un *hilo*, pero no en ese caso:

> [...] tuvo que acostumbrarse a su miserable rutina de huérfano, señalado por todos como el hijo de la viuda que llevó al pueblo el trono de la desgracia, viviendo no tanto de la caridad pública como del pescado que se robaba en los botes, mientras **la voz se le iba volviendo de *bramante*** y sin acordarse más de sus visiones de antaño hasta otra noche de marzo en que miró por casualidad 
>   hacia el mar, y de pronto, madre mía, ahí está, la descomunal ballena de amianto, la bestia berraca, vengan a verlo, gritaba...

Comment: ¡Hola Livius! Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Buena e interesante pregunta. Fíjate que hice algún cambio estilístico, como poner un título más descriptivo. ¿Podrías aportar un fragmento más extenso de la cita? Para tener más contexto. ¿Crees que será un regionalismo colombiano?

Comment: This was migrated from linguistics, where @boiko suggested: "It means screaming, bellowing. Same as French bramer, Portuguese bramar etc. Cool word of Germanic origins (cp. Dutch brommen)."

Comment: Here's a translation by Gregory Rabassa: "while his voice was becoming a roar."  http://www.napavalley.edu/people/LYanover/Documents/English%20121/English%20121%20Gabriel%20Garcia%20Marquez%20The%20Last%20Voyage%20of%20the%20Ghost%20Ship.pdf

Comment: no nos olvidemos del toro bramador !

Answer (score 3):

#### Opción 1

Puede que esté usando *bramante*, no como sustantivo, sino como adjetivo derivado del verbo **bramar**:

> [**bramar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=62YvCuE)
>
> 1. intr. Dar bramidos.
> 2. intr. Dicho de una persona: Manifestar con voces articuladas o inarticuladas y con extraordinaria violencia la ira de que está poseída.
> 3. intr. Dicho especialmente del viento o del mar violentamente agitados: Hacer ruido estrepitoso.

Por tanto "bramante" significaría "que brama: que da voces fuertes y con violencia para expresar su ira".

Se pueden construir adjetivos a partir de verbos añadiéndoles la terminación [-nte](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QgZMpot). Estos adjetivos se llaman a veces "participio activo" del verbo en cuestión, y quieren decir "que lleva a cabo la acción indicada". Por ejemplo: *agobiar → agobiante, caminar → caminante*, etc.

El motivo de que meta un "de" ahí en medio, es decir que diga "voz *de* bramante" en vez de "voz bramante" puede ser por razones estilísticas, por algún fenómeno similar al dequeísmo, porque esté haciendo elipsis del nombre ("voz de (persona) bramante") o por simple error gramatical, que todos cometemos alguno de vez en cuando.

#### Opción 2

Tras ver el texto completo, creo que en realidad sí que puede estar refiriéndose al hilo de bramante: quiere decir que, con el paso de los años y las penas, **la voz se le fue quedando fina, áspera y seca, como un hilo de bramante**.
Es un símil buenísimo, porque usa "bramante" para describirnos esa voz como *exactamente lo contrario* de lo que significa "bramante" aplicado a una voz. Puro genio.

Comment: Con respecto a la opción 1 (que me parece la mejor) la definición del diccionario de _bramidos_ dice "voz del toro, del ciervo y de otros animales salvajes". O sea que "voz de bramante" podría significar "voz de animal salvaje".